# use $rootScope in my own directive

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use $rootScope inside directive which I creadted.
This directive has isolated scope - it might be the problem but I cannot give up this isolated scope for several reasons..
I tried to ineject $rootScope to my directive but it was unsuccessful.
The code of the directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    'restrict': 'AE',
    'templateUrl': 'my/template/url.html',
    'scope': {
      something: "="
    },
    'controller': function($rootScope,$scope, $timeout, toaster) {
      console.log($rootScope.name);
    }
  }
});
```

The code in app.run:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, defaultErrorMessageResolver, usersService, contactsService) {

  $rootScope.name = "hello";
  $rootScope.getUser = function() {
    //do something
  };

});
```

I tried to look for solution on web and found nothing.
What might be the problem and how can I fix it (if at all)?

Comment: *I tried to ineject $rootScope to my directive but it was unsuccessful*: then post what you tried, and post the error you got.

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "It was unsuccessful" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Comment: Works fine in this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/SwAgm200bGC7PjAheVbg?p=preview).

Comment: @georgeawg "unsuccessful" means that still I dont have access to the $rootScope from the directive. I think this meaining is obvious.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can refer rootScope reference by calling `$scope.$root` (which has link to $rootScope)